# Recommendation for a Guitar tuner

Tags: software-recommendation, sound, music

I tried searching for a guitar tuner for Ubuntu(something similar to PitchPerfect tuner for Windows) and installed lingot but couldn't get it to work. Which guitar tuner do you guys suggest?

I hope this isn't the wrong place for this question!!

Answer (score 19):

I've tried them all, and IMHO [**LINGOT**](http://linuxappfinder.com/package/lingot) is the easiest Guitar Tuner available on Linux.

More about it:

> LINGOT is a musical instrument tuner.
>   It's accurate, easy-to-use, and highly
>   configurable. Originally designed as a
>   guitar and bass tuner, its
>   configurability gives it a more
>   general character. It looks like an
>   analog tuner, with a gauge indicating
>   the relative shift to a certain note.
>   The program automatically guesses the
>   note to tune.

Related to this toppic, **Rakarrack** is the best Guitar Effects software out there. Before using it, you'll need to configure JACK (*qjackctl*) to connect the guitar audio input to the speakers output (at [this link](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/rakarrack-guitar-fx-linux) you'll find more info about how to use Rakarrack).

Comment: Doesn't recognise my microphone, no option to sound the tones so that I can tune by ear... Back to [Flash web apps](http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/tuner/), I guess :P

Comment: Lingot was over sensitive: the needle was jumping quickly from left to right. I increased  the noise treshold to 40db, under Edit / Preferences / Adjustments / Noise Threshold. After that, It became usable, I could tune my guitar allrigt.

Answer (score 4):

**Guitar Tuner**

> Guitar Tuner is a software allowing to tune a guitar according to a defined chord

[Guitar Tuner on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/guitartuner/)

**GuiTuner**

> GuiTuner is a simple guitar tuning program for Linux.
>
> GuiTuner tries to detect the pitch of the sound recorded in real time from the audio device using some methods ( by now only based on FFT ) that you can configure at runtime. It is self-explanatory, you just have to connect your guitar or your microphone to the sound card, configure the input device using a mixer and see what the program tells you: it displays the note nearest to the picked sound and the interval between it and the note produced by the instrument. If the sound produced is lower than the right one the left arrow becomes green, if is higher becomes green the right arrow.

[Gui Tuner on digilander.libero.it](https://digilander.libero.it/guituner/)

**Online**

You can also use an [online guitar tuner](http://www.online-guitar-tuner.net/).

Comment: @Alaukik- Both of the softwares you mentioned had problems running on my laptop

Comment: what problems were there?

Comment: None works for me: GuiTuner is not installable on 12.10 because of unresolved (deprecated) dependencies, and GuitarTuner suffers from graphical glitches.

LINGOT, mentioned below by @valadao, works fine though. Give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

[fmit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/fmit) [image: Install gparted] / `sudo apt-get install fmit` is included in the regular software sources. It was the only one that worked for me. Although you will need to fine tune a few of the settings. With older versions of Ubuntu I had the problem, that the sample rate was low, when the sound preferences were not open (weird - I know). A workaround to that is using pulseaudios oss-wrapper by starting fmit with:

```
padsp fmit
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert and haven't used it, but [Rakarrack](http://rakarrack.sourceforge.net/) sounds like it will fit the bill.  It's primarily an effects pedal, but also features a tuner.  Combined with Ardour or Audacity, it should let you plug your guitar straight into your Ubuntu PC and start recording.

Comment: @Scaine-Actually I want to be able to do it without plugging the guitar. The WIndows software I mentioned above(Pitchperfect) does this with a microphone.

Comment: This could be overkill then.  But if you're using Windows software for your recording, then why the Ubuntu question?

Comment: Both [Longot](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/lingot) and [GtkGuitune](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gtkguitune) don't seem to work for me, it looks like they don't play nice with the modern pulseaudio stack in Ubuntu.

Comment: Just tried GtkGuitune and it didn't work either.  Seems that there's no `/dev/dsp` on my system.  Perhaps if I knew where my sound card was, I could specify it with `--device=`.

Answer (score 1):

Try fmit :
http://home.gna.org/fmit/

It's available in Debian and Ubuntu repositories.  It supports all the major Linux audio system standards, so I don't see any problems with it working on your system.

If you have trouble with fmit, then you probably need to poke around to learn some basics about Linux sound systems.  It's not always 100% plug & play, but usually the answer is simple when you find it.

No problem using the microphone.  Scaine probably meant whatever means you have to get guitar sound into the computer.

Comment: New URL: https://gillesdegottex.github.io/fmit